# How to get totals for each age category?

Tags: sql, proc-sql

```
proc sql;
 create table final as select drink,
 count(distinct id) as total_persons,
 count(distinct case when age_cat = '20-25' then id end) as tot_20_25, 
 count(distinct case when age_cat = '25-30' then id end) astot_25_30, 
 count(distinct case when age_cat = '30-35' then id end) as tot_30_35 
 from old_table
 group by drink
 order by total_persons
 quit;
```

This table gives me what i want,but i would like one more row as  the totals for all persons and for each category.I can get that single row with correct number if remove from above code the group by steatement.
Is any way to have both cases,by drinks ,and also in same table totals for each category?

Comment: You are clearly using proc-sql so I changed the tag.  If this is a pass-through query to MySQL, you should be clear.

Comment: [SAS GROUP BY Rollup?](https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Programming/Rollup/td-p/15255)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `union all`:

```
proc sql;
 create table final as
     select drink,
            count(distinct id) as total_persons,
            count(distinct case when age_cat = '20-25' then id end) as tot_20_25, 
            count(distinct case when age_cat = '25-30' then id end) as tot_25_30, 
            count(distinct case when age_cat = '30-35' then id end) as tot_30_35 
     from old_table
     group by drink
     union all
     select 'Total',
            count(distinct id) as total_persons,
            count(distinct case when age_cat = '20-25' then id end) as tot_20_25, 
            count(distinct case when age_cat = '25-30' then id end) as tot_25_30, 
            count(distinct case when age_cat = '30-35' then id end) as tot_30_35 
     from old_table;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Gordon.